# "The 128x128 icon file is missing" error when publishing Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm getting a serious issue with uploading an app to Chrome Store. Keeps saying:

"An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

The 128x128 icon file is missing.".

I do have the 128x128 .png file in there. This is my .json file:

```
{
    "name": "Radio Player UK",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Radio, but without the rubbish. The best radio stations are here. Choose from lots of great radio stations.",
    "app":{
        "urls": ["http://www.radioplayeruk.com"],
        "launch":{
            "web_url": "http://www.radioplayeruk.com/index.php"
        }
    },
    "icons":{
        "icons": {
            "16": "logo16.png",
            "128": "logo.png"
        }
    }
}
```

I know the file extensions are case sensitive and have adjusted this accordingly.

Can anybody shed some light on why I keep getting this message?

Comment: Are icon filenames exactly as you have written them? Ensure you put it exactly as it is (check if there's a capital letter on the filename or the extension).

Comment: The name on the file and the file extension is exactly how it is on the .json file. I've actually copied and pasted from the file name to make sure it's exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `icons` twice. [According to the Google docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) it should be just one `icons` key.

So, your manifest should be:

```
{
    "name": "Radio Player UK",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Radio, but without the rubbish. The best radio stations are here. Choose from lots of great radio stations.",
    "app":{
        "urls": ["http://www.radioplayeruk.com"],
        "launch":{
            "web_url": "http://www.radioplayeruk.com/index.php"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo16.png",
        "128": "logo.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a GENIUS. Thanks!

Comment: I've never did a Google app, just went to the documentation, edited your question and saw that `icons` key twice. I'm glad I helped you ^^